# Different error's in different browser's while running a WebPage

Tags: asp.net, radgrid

There is a Web Form in which there are few asp.net controls (Textbox, Radiobutton, button) and few Telerik controls (2 RadGrid - say **RadGrid_Account** and **RadGrid_GST**)

In above 2 `RadGrid`, user can add/edit/delete/show the records.

**RadGrid_GST** is working fine and it is inside `RadAjaxPanel`.

In **RadGrid_Account** radgrid, Add/Edit mode has 3 fields:
1) GridTemplateColumn --> EditItemTemplate has RadCombobox with asp Button next to it.
2) 2 GridBoundColumn 
This radgrid is also inside `RadAjaxPanel`.

**Issue is:**

- When the **RadGrid_Account** is inside `RadAjaxPanel`, and user click on `Add New` button,
  Add/Edit panel opens along with above 3 fields.

Now when user type any text in `RadCombobox` and click on asp `button`, provided next to `RadComboBox`, searching related to key-in text starts and the web page starts loading too (Note that the Items that has to bind in RadComboBox, related to key-in text, may contain 10000+ records)
and despite of having records in database related to searched text, 
nothing comes up after button click.

- Again, When I comment the `RadAjaxPanel` of **RadGrid_Account** (just to test the functionality), and user click on `Add New` button,
  Add/Edit panel opens along with above 3 fields.

Now when user type any text in `RadCombobox` and click on asp `button`, provided next to `RadComboBox`, searching related to key-in text starts and the web page starts loading too (Note that the Items that has to bind in `RadComboBox`, related to key-in text, may sometimes contain 10000+ records)
If the records that need to bind in RadComboBox are less, then it shows the records, and if they are more than 10,000 it shows below errors.

After clicking on button page keeps on loading and after some time it display

> below error in Chrome browser:

[image]

> and below error in IE browser:

[image]

Please note that I have to put this RadGrid_Account inside `RadAjaxPanel`, can not comment it.

Same code I am using in another page and there its working fine without any issue then why its showing these errors in this particular page?

I read below link, but could not get it:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/981884

Please let me know what does this error means ? and what is wrong in my Web page ? I am first time facing this error. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the filtering logic in `StoredProcedure`, that I was doing before from code behind.
i.e., removed below line of code from .aspx.cs page:

```
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("AccountDescription LIKE '%{0}%'", txt);
```

and added this logic in `StoredProcedure` query. All is working fine now.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual code, the only thing I can tell is that your Ajax control is trying to return a Json string that is longer than [MaxJsonLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength.aspx).

Comment: thank you for the reply. Please let me know where and how to set this property and how to resolve this issue ? Please reply